# Counting repeated values in array Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to practice my algorithm skills. I know there is already an algorithm written out there, I just want to try it on my own and see how close i could get.

INPUT:

```
arr1 = ['asd','ew','lol','asd']
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
{ asd: 2, ew: 1, lol: 1 }
```

This is my code:

```js
arr1 = ['asd', 'ew', 'lol', 'asd']
arr2 = []
results = {}

function checkIfExists(word) {
  if (arr2.length != 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
      if (arr2[i] == word) {
        results[word] += 1
      } else {
        arr2.push(word)
        results[word] = 1
      }
    }
  } else {
    arr2.push(word)
    results[word] = 1
  }
}

for (i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  checkIfExists(arr1[i])
}
console.log(results)
```

ACTUAL OUTPUT:

```
{ asd: 2, ew: 2 }
```

Comment: Ok fine this is your code. What is the problem you are facing . What is the question?

Comment: The first problem is that you are not using `var` to declare `i`. That causes both loops to interfere with each other. But even if you fix that you won't get the desired result. What have you done so far to debug your code? Do you have a *specific* question?

Comment: @Manish The intent should be pretty clear: there’s an expected result and an actual result. The title reveals what the code is supposed to do. This is more information than most questions on Stack Overflow provide.

Comment: @Xufox Agreed (and +1d) but I think Manish does have a point... There's no question (identified by a question mark) here! How are we to know whether the OP is asking *"What's wrong with my code?"*, *"Why is my code producing an incorrect output?"* and *"How do I fix my code?"*, which are three subtly different questions for example?

Comment: Correct @Seb that's my point as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `i` as a global variable, so don't use for two loop. Other mistake is in your increment algorithm that add more than needed count to results array. So try it:

```js
arr1 = ['asd','ew','lol','asd']
arr2 = [] 
results = {}

function checkIfExists(word){
    if (arr2.length != 0){
     var exists = false;
      for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++){
        if(arr2[j] == word){
          results[word] += 1
          exists = true;
          break;          
        }
      }
      if(!exists) {
          arr2.push(word)
          results[word] = 1
        }
    }else{
      arr2.push(word)
       results[word] = 1 
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    checkIfExists(arr1[i])
}
console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three questions I identified immediately which you might have intended to ask.

1. **What's wrong with my code?**

   - I couldn't phrase this better than [Felix Klings comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44469502/counting-repeated-values-in-array-javascript#comment75935125_44469502):

     > The first problem is that you are not using `var` to declare `i`.
   - The loop presumably intended to locate an item within `arr2` *also modifies* `arr2`... **a lot!**
2. **Why is my code producing incorrect output?** Your code is actually producing *correct* output for the logic it expresses. I suspect the issue is that the logic it expresses doesn't match the logic you intended to express. This isn't uncommon
3. **How do I fix my code?**

   - Start by changing your loop idioms from `for (i = ...)` to `for (var i = ...)`.
   - Think about the purpose of *that loop*. If it's intended to locate an item within `arr2`, then it shouldn't need to modify `arr2` to do so. Perhaps you don't need the loop;

     1. You could probably use [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) or [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) in place of that entire loop!
     2. You could probably use `function checkIfExists(word) { results[word] = arr1.filter(function(w) { return w === word; }).length; }` in place of that entire function!
     3. It seems like you could use some higher-level awareness when designing functions, so perhaps it might be a good idea to try to wrap your head around some of the elements in this code:

---

```
var arr1 = ['asd','ew','lol','asd'];
var result = arr1.reduce(function(result, w) { result[w] = result[w] || 0;
                                               result[w]++;
                                               return result;              }, {}));
console.log(result);
```